# How should I integrate this?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, improper-integrals, education

Could someone help integrate the following integral please:
$$
\int\biggr(1+u+\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{u^3}{6}+\frac{u^4}{24}+\frac{u^5}{120}\biggr)^{-1/2} \mathrm{d}x
$$
Where,
$$
u = \left(\frac{x-35.8}{0.554}\right)^2
$$
I've tried using the following formula but it doesn't seem to yield the right answer:
$$\int_{38}^{\infty} (ax+b)^c \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{a} \frac{(ax+b)^{c+1}}{c+1}$$
If you can't get the answer but at least make some progress, it would be greatly appreciated if you could reply anyways.

Comment: The inner part seems like a taylor series for $e^x$.

Comment: Yes, it's a taylor series for $$e^{x^2}$$

Comment: Try Wolfram alpha

Comment: It says it exceeds the standard computation time...seems like its too large

Comment: There no antiderivative in elementary functions, or even in terms of elliptic integrals.

Comment: So it's not possible to integrate?

Comment: Definite integral can be evaluated numerically.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate an improper integral.
$$\int_{3.258}^{\infty}$$

Comment: Hi, hope you're well! Do you need to truncate the series or you may consider the complete expansion?

Comment: Could you clarify what that means?

Comment: Without the square root, your integrand looks like a truncated expansion of an exponential as already commented

Comment: Oh I see, if the integration is possible with the complete expansion I could use that instead

Comment: Great, definitely it will look better! Try to integrate $1/\sqrt{e^{u(x)}}$ now. :D

Comment: I can integrate that but can I ask how you arrived at that formula?

Comment: Of course! I will post it as an answer now. Give me a minute.

Comment: It is the question you had posted some hours ago but without explaining how $u$ is expressed as a function of $x$ !!!

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiarized with Taylor series, is easy to see that
$$
e^{u(x)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{u(x)^k}{k!}.
$$
In your case, you must plug in your $u(x)$. Try to compute some terms and see that you will end up with the same summation as your integrand (avoiding the square root).

If you want to compute the integral using the complete expansion and not a truncated one (which it seems to be quite difficult or rather impossible to compute analitically), you will end up with
$$
\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{e^{u(x)}}} \qquad \text{ with } \qquad u(x) = \left(\frac{x-35.8}{0.554}\right)^2,
$$
so $e^{u(x)}$ looks like a gaussian function. Its indefinite integral can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions, but "we can deal with it" using the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html). The indefinite integral [returns](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%201%2Fsqrt%28e%5E%28%28%28x-35.8%29%2F0.554%29%5E2%29%29)
$$
\boxed{\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{e^{u(x)}}} = 0.554\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{erf}(1.276 (x-35.8)) + C.}\tag{1}\label{eq:indefinite}
$$

If you want to compute it with bounds setting a lower bound $x_0$, [then](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%201%2Fsqrt%28e%5E%28%28%28x-35.8%29%2F0.554%29%5E2%29%29%20from%20x%3Da%20to%20x%3Dinf)
$$
\boxed{\int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{e^{u(x)}}} = 0.554\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left[1-\mathrm{erf}(1.276(x_0-35.8))\right].}
$$

Just for completness, this is how it looks \eqref{eq:indefinite} setting $C=0$.

[image: Error function]

Comment: Thank you so much! You were very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting this answer as a solution.